# How to write constructor when in an MVC API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I am trying to write an API project in code first approach. I written some code but it shows error

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'CatalogController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

and

> Type `Nop.Api.Controllers.CatalogController` does not have a default constructor

Controller

```
public class CatalogController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICatalogModelFactory _catalogModelFactory;
   
    public CatalogController(ICatalogModelFactory catalogModelFactory)
    {
        _catalogModelFactory = catalogModelFactory;           
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage HomepageCategories()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var model = _catalogModelFactory.PrepareHomepageCategoryModels();

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(result) };
   
        return response;
     }
}
```

Can anyone please help me how solve this error? I am not getting what is wrong in the constructor part. When debugging this it is not hitting the breakpoint.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you setting the [dependency resolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx) to use your DI container?

Comment: Are you using a dependency injection framework? If so, can you include the details of how you have set it up, and how you have registered the dependency resolver. If not, then this is your problem, have a search on how to use a framework like Ninject, SimpleInjector, or Autofac for ASP.NET.

Comment: Which version of asp.net do you use?

Answer (score 1):

When you request a resource from a controller, the framework needs to process the request. So the routing identifies the controller, action etc. and then it needs to instantiate an instance of the controller in order to invoke the wanted method.

In order to do that, he will either need a public empty constructor or some way to resolve your constructor's dependencies.

In your case, you have one ctor that has a dependency of *ICatalogModelFactory*. The framework will need you to implement a [Dependency Resolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx) and register you new resolver when the application starts (Global.asax) like this:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new MyDependencyResolver());
```

Here's and example of a UnityContainer custom dependency resolver as found in this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator):

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{        
    IUnityContainer container;       
    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {               
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {                
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

And the registration occurred in the Global.asax Application_Start method:

```
IUnityContainer container = GetUnityContainer();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

By the way, another way to do so, is to create a [ControllerFactory](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/878/custom-controller-factory-aspnet-mvc) and simply resolve the controller with a DI container. I prefer using the dependency resolver for resolving controllers.

Comment: Do you have a DI container in your application?

Comment: Then how are you supposed to resolve the ICatalogModelFactory input parameter? You cannot instantiate an interface and therefore you will need some kind of concrete class.